# Convert data to associated array php

Tags: php, associative-array

Is it possible in php to convert this kind of data

```
    ABANO TERME A001
ABBADIA CERRETO A004
ABBADIA LARIANA A005
ABBADIA SAN SALVATORE   A006
ABBASANTA   A007
ABBATEGGIO  A008
ABBIATEGRASSO   A010
```

to an associated array where in the first column are keys and in the second column are values?

Comment: Yes. Where does the data come from and what do you have so far?

Comment: Is it string or what kind of data it is?

Comment: Do you mean `$myArr["ABETONE"] = "A012";`?

Comment: @Gaurav i have data in a .txt file in the format i have shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen(path\to\file\filename, "r");
$result_arr = array();
while(($filesop = fgets($handle)) !== false)
{
    $line_arr = explode(" ", $filesop);
    $value = end($line_arr);
    unset($line_arr[array_search($value, $line_arr)]);
    $key = implode(" ", $line_arr);
    $result_arr[trim($key] = trim($value);
}
print_r($result_arr);
```

Store in the text file like this (separated by commas):

```
ABANO TERME,A001
ABBADIA CERRETO,A004
ABBADIA LARIANA,A005
ABBADIA SAN SALVATORE,A006
ABBASANTA,A007
ABBATEGGIO,A008
ABBIATEGRASSO,A010
```

Solution to read file:

```
$handle = fopen(path\to\file\filename, "r");
$result_arr = array();
while(($filesop = fgets($handle)) !== false)
{
    $line_arr = explode(",", $filesop);
    $value = end($line_arr);
    unset($line_arr[array_search($value, $line_arr)]);
    $key = implode(",", $line_arr);
    $result_arr[trim($key] = trim($value);
}
print_r($result_arr);
```

Comment: i updated my question because my data may be as i have shown now but if i explode with space they are misinterpreted @JustCarty

Comment: @Gaurav it throws an error: Undefined offset: 0. Sorry but  i am a beginner in php

Comment: @Gaurav Array ( [ABANO] => TERME A001 [ABBADIA] => LARIANA A005 [ABBADIA SAN] => SALVATORE A006 [] => ZUNGRI M204 [ACI] => SANT'ANTONIO A029 [ACQUANEGRA] 
this is the output still misinterpreted :(

Comment: @belka Is it possible to change each row so they are delimited by a "," and then change the `explode` and `implode` to use a ","?

Comment: @JustCarty but in belka question text file don't have any comma. So we have to wait.

Comment: @JustCarty so if my data are 
ABANO TERME A001,
ABBADIA CERRETO A004,
ABBADIA LARIANA A005,
ABBADIA SAN SALVATORE A006,
ABBASANTA A007
i have to do explode','?

Comment: @JustCarty then first of all explode line by comma then in loop you have to use my code.

Comment: @belka indeed, just make sure there are no unwanted spaces either side of the "," although we could use trim? See the new answer.

Comment: @JustCarty i approved your suggested edit. Also keep old without which is without comma seperated.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $txt = file_get_contents('foo.txt');
    $arr=array_values(array_filter(explode(' ',$txt)));
    $new=[];
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr)-1;$i++){

    $new[$arr[$i]]=$arr[++$i];
    }

    print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this particular data would be:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('data.txt')

//use regular expressions to parse whole file at once
preg_match_all("/([^\s]+\s?[^\s]+?)\s+(.\d+)$/m", $data, $m);

//and combine results from result array ($m)
//first entry - $m[0] contains whole lines thats why I dont use it here
//second entry - $m[1] - data from first brackets is an array key
//third entry - $m[2] - is a value (both are separated by some number of spaces - \s+)
$array = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

print_r($array);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [ABETONE] => A012
    [ABRIOLA] => A013
    [ACATE] => A014
    [ACCADIA] => A015
)
```

of course, as colleagues above pointed out, this depends on where data came from, and if this particular set is representative.

Comment: I have cases when keys are two words like:

ACQUAVIVA COLLECROCE A050
ACQUAVIVA D'ISERNIA A051
in this case the keys and values are misinterpreted. Can this be fixed?